# ResourceBundle/Propertie file to accept array of String in argument {0}

Tags: java, localization, resources

Is there a way to pass an array of String to a resource bundle to localize an unknown number of argument for a given key?

I have:

```
my.message=List of retired products: {0}

getValue(bundle, "my.message", list.toArray());
```

With this, only the first item in the array is showed in the resulting message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no builtin facilities for that in the [`MessageFormat` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). You need to build a string with the values yourself. E.g.:

```
StringBuilder products = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    products.append(list.get(i));
    if (i + 2 < list.size()) products.append(", ");
    else if (i + 2 == list.size()) products.append(" and "); // Localize this?
}
getValue(bundle, "my.message", products);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going to need a `for` loop.